# Не компилируется код в C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

const p = 10;
 char V[p] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'};
 char y = j;
 char i;
 int ok = 0;
 char aux;
 int n;


 printf("Input the value of y \n" );
 scanf("%c", &y);

 while(ok == 0){
    ok = 1;
    for(j=0; j<p-1;j++){
        if(V[j]==y){
            if(V[j]>V[j+1]){
                aux = V[j];
                V[j] = V[j+1];
                V[j+1] = aux;
                ok = 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            for(i=j;i<n;i++){
                V[i] = V[i+1];
                n--;
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Вкратце у меня есть задание где дается вектор V с p компонентами занятый элементами из массива A = { a, b, c, d, e, f },и дается переменная y:
Нужно определить:
a)нужно вычислить если заданая переменная y находится в массиве А
б)Если переменная y не нашлась в массиве A то массив должен отстортироватся по возрастанию и y должен занять должное ему место,к примеру мы задали переменной y букву g,то массив должен отстортироватся по возрастанию и поместить букву g после буквы f
в)Если переменная y уже находится в массиве то совпадающий элемент нужно удалить и переместить массив влево,к примеру мы задали переменной y букву C,комп. находит совпадение,удаляет из памяти элемент c,и перемещает весь массив в левую сторону

Я слепил такой вот код,но компилятор ругается с ошибкой

> variable-sized object may be not initialized,ошибка в 7 строке то есть в char V[p]

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, **конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения** прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: исправил описание

Comment: .. и **минимальный** код для её воспроизведения ..

Answer (score 0):

```
const int p = 10;  // Не экономьте на `int` :)

char y = j;
...
for(j=0; j<p-1;j++){
```

Скажите, а что такое у вас `j` и чему оно равно? Вот и компилятор тоже не в состоянии понять...

Исправите эти ошибки - скомпилируется. Но запомните: успешная компиляция и правильная работа - это две не очень сильно коррелирующие вещи...

Comment: В моём замысле j = позиции где Y был

Comment: Откуда это следует? У вас нет объявления `j`, его инициализации. Вы сами этого не видите?

Comment: да я не заметил что пропустил его,исправил код и отправил его выше

Answer (score 0):

Это Си и, видимо, не новый. Так что замени http://codepad.org/4Nx8yfEO

> ```
> const p = 10;
> ```

на http://codepad.org/KB16XffU

```
#define p 10
```

Но лучше вынести из функции и назвать заглавными буквами  http://codepad.org/ST66vF81

```
#define MAXLEN 10

int main()
{
  char V[MAXLEN] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'};
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

 #define p 10
 char V[p] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'};
 char j;
 char y;
 char i;
 int ok = 0;
 char aux;
 int n;


 printf("Input the value of y \n" );
 scanf("%c", &y);

 while(ok == 0){
    ok = 1;
    for(j=0; j<p-1;j++){
        if(V[j]==y){
            if(V[j]>V[j+1]){
                aux = V[j];
                V[j] = V[j+1];
                V[j+1] = aux;
                ok = 0;
            }
            printf("%c", V[i]);

        }
        else {
            for(i=j;i<n;i++){
                V[i] = V[i+1];
                n--;
            }
            printf("%c", V[i]);
        }
    }
 }

}
```

Исправил свой код,теперь при компиляции если я ввожую новый элемент который не состоит в массиве то на выводе получаю abcdefg, а если я напишу элемент который уже состоит в массиве к примеру c,то получу abbdefg,что нужно изменить чтобы в первой части вопроса к массиву прибавился новый элемент, и во второй части удалился совпадающий и массив переместился влево